# Implementing markers into Google Maps using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having problems implementing JSON data into Google Maps as markers usign Angular. My JSON data is:

```
 [
  {
    "_id": "TRK45679101121",
    "timestamp": "2015-02-03T09:18:02.989Z",
    "status": 1,
    "path": [
      {
        "timestamp": 51422955082989,
        "speed": 30,
        "direction": 45.510029,
        "longitude": 81.510029,
        "latitude": 8.675009
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "TRK456799",
    "timestamp": "2015-02-03T09:18:02.989Z",
    "status": 1,
    "path": [
      {
        "timestamp": 51422955082989,
        "speed": 30,
        "direction": 45.510029,
        "longitude": 81.510029,
        "latitude": 8.675009
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": null,
    "timestamp": "2016-01-22T08:10:43.238Z",
    "status": null,
    "path": null
  }
]
```

Do you know how one can read this through JavaScript and integrate into the Google Maps API? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Note:**  I only need to implement the latitude and longitude. In case the marker is clicked, the "_id" and "status" needs to show, which I'll look into later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. The Angular controller uses the JSON data contained in the global variable `mydata` and uses it to add some markers to the map. The markers' info is also available in the Angular `$scope`.

```js
var mydata = [{
  "_id": "TRK45679101121",
  "timestamp": "2015-02-03T09:18:02.989Z",
  "status": 1,
  "path": [{
    "timestamp": 51422955082989,
    "speed": 30,
    "direction": 45.510029,
    "longitude": 31.510029,
    "latitude": 8.675009
  }]
}, {
  "_id": "TRK456799",
  "timestamp": "2015-02-03T09:18:02.989Z",
  "status": 1,
  "path": [{
    "timestamp": 51422955082989,
    "speed": 30,
    "direction": 45.510029,
    "longitude": 32.510029,
    "latitude": 12.675009
  }]
}];

//Angular App Module and Controller
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
  .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(31, 8),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function(lat, lng) {

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: "lat: " + lat + ",lng: " + lng
      });

      $scope.markers.push(marker);

    }
    
    $http({method: 'GET', url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Canada&sensor=true&region=USA"}).
        success(function(data, status) {
          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.JSONdata = data;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.JSONdata = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
          console.log($scope.data+$scope.status);
      });
    

    for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
      console.log(mydata[i]["path"][0]["longitude"], mydata[i]["path"][0]["latitude"]);
      createMarker(mydata[i]["path"][0]["longitude"],mydata[i]["path"][0]["latitude"]);
    }

  });
```

```css
#map {
  height: 420px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&extension=.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
  <H3>
Markers
</H3>
  <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
    {{marker.position}}
  </div>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
```

EDIT: to retrieve the JSON data from a remote HTTP server, use Angular's [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). In the example the response data is saved in `$scope.JSONdata` and can be used in place of `mydata`.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. :) However I have this data being returned in an API endpoint. Is there a way to call the data from the endpoint into the angular script?

Comment: Oops, my bad. Apologies!

Comment: Is it possible to show markers by using angularjs response data from database?.I am using same code but i am getting data from database in angularjs function as response.Here is the link to my question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46461477/loading-address-data-into-google-maps-from-database-using-angularjs/46462236?noredirect=1#comment79880086_46462236

Comment: If u find some time please go through it .It will be very helpful