# Loading address data into google maps from database using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am using angularjs for my application.I am trying to load the address from user_address table in database and display it on map on load.

Here is the script i am using to load google maps

```
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
    key=myKey&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Here is the html

```
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="repeatmap" data-ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy :
    'title'">
    <a id="country_container" href="#" ng-
    click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">
    <label id="namesformap" >{{marker.title}}</label></a>
    </div>
```

Here is the Controller.js

```
    var DirectoryController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http,
    $location, $route,DirectoryService,HomeService,$routeParams) 
    {

    $scope.getAllCities = function()
    {
        DirectoryService.getAllCities().then(function(response){
        $scope.cities = response.data;
        console.log($scope.cities);
    })
    }

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(25,80),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);
    $scope.markers = [];
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var createMarker = function (info){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.city
     });
     marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc +
     '</div>';
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
     infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + 
     marker.content);
     infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
     });
     $scope.markers.push(marker);
     }  

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++){
        createMarker($scope.cities[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
        }
    }
```

In getAllCities function i am getting response from database that is all the names of cities.

As you can see in console i am able to get the response from database but i am not able to get $scope.cities value to for loop.It is saying Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.Can anyone tell how can i get value of $scope.cities into for loop so that in map i can display the cities returned from database.Now i am able to display map but with no cities and no markers.I dont know whether it will work or not or am i doing the wrong way?

Comment: Since the request from the database is probably asynchronous, perhaps the response hasn't been resolved before you try to add your markers. Try waiting with setting up the map until after your data has been resolved (i.e. call your map setup code from the `then`-callback).

Comment: Can u please elaborate on this? Now i am getting all cities as response from database

Comment: Put all the code shown in your `Controller.js` snippet into a function (I can't tell from the code you've shared whether you already do this). Call that function from within the `then`-function. If it's not clear enough, I ask you to add a bit more code to your snippets, in order to see the context this code is executed in.

Comment: Do i have to place it inside getAllCities .then callback?

Comment: Yes. After you assign `$scope.cities = response.data`. That way you're certain your request to the database has resolved when you attempt to add the markers.

Comment: That is all the code i am using.getAllCities function is also in Controller.js.Can u please suggest how can i place it inside the getAllCities function?.Will be really helpful

Comment: It would be helpful to see the entire controller, i.e. the context where the snippet above lives.

Comment: I have updated my question.I have added entire controller i am using

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you're trying to add the markers before the request to the database has finished resolving. This happens because the database/webservice request is most likely executed asynchronously.

Instead run the code for setting up the markers, when your promise from the database request have resolved. Like this:

```
var DirectoryController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $route,DirectoryService, HomeService, $routeParams) 
{
    $scope.getAllCities = function()
    {
        DirectoryService.getAllCities().then(function(response){
            $scope.cities = response.data;
            console.log($scope.cities);
            setupMapMarkers();
        });
    }

    function setupMapMarkers(){
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(25,80),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }

        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        $scope.markers = [];
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cities.length; i++){
            createMarker($scope.cities[i]);
        }

        $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
            e.preventDefault();
            google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
        }
    }

    function createMarker(info){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.city
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
        $scope.markers.push(marker);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I tried with this code.But the map itself not displaying

Comment: That's probably an entirely different problem. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors.simply displaying empty.previously it was loading google maps.

Comment: It is displaying that initMap is not a function

Comment: In the script where you include Google maps, it references a `initMap`-callback. Perhaps you need to create such a callback.

Comment: In the function createMarker in title i am displaying it as info.city.But i am getting $scope.cities as response.Inside cities i have city.Can u please tell how to display city

Comment: Now i am able to display map and under map if i am having 5 cities in db it is displaying 5 times as cities.But marker is not showing

Comment: In markers the total length of cities are coming.And it is displaying under the map as 5 boxes because total cities count is 5.But the markers are not showing up in map.

Comment: That question is a bit outside the scope of the original question - which I assume have been resolved? This tangent question is a bit difficult to answer without sitting with the code myself, can you perhaps produce a Plunker or similar, with a minimal sample that shows this new problem?